# Wrong Email Template is being sent from the community after password reset 5 times

Tags: community, email-template, customer-community, lightning-community

We have a Community with Customer Service template. There are Custom Templates for Emails like Welcome, Forgot/Change Password, etc. Please check the image below.
[image]

All emails are being sent with the right Email Template except the Change Password email in the case when the user used **forgot password** link 5 times. SF blocks the user and sends the email that the user is blocked for 24 hours. 
[image]

I set Custom Email Template for Change Password Email (see 1 pic) but it is not being sent. I checked the standard template Communities: User Lockout Email but there is different content. And our Custom User Lockout Email also has different content.

So, I cannot understand which Email Template it is. Here is Custom Reset Password content that must be sent instead of first one:

> Hi test, We have recently received a request to reset your TRAXEE password.  We
>   cannot reset your password as you attempted to reset your password too
>   many times within the last 24 hours.  Please try again later.  If you
>   did not request a password reset, please contact WABCO or reply to
>   this email.
>   Best Regards,
>   WABCO

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that when User clicked Forgot Password link, you expect them to receive the Email with the template as configured in the Change Password?

Comment: @JayantDas, I expect to receive that email when the user clicked Forgot Password link 5 times. I expect it will send Change Password which is Reset Password template.

Comment: Same issue, was there ever a resolution to this?

Comment: @dphil Probably yes, but I don`t remember after 4 years...